# BTP - GET_USER_ALIAS returns empty value

Tags: abap, sap-business-technology-platform

Hi I made my first Hello World in BTP and it didn't show my user alias...

Why?

[image: ABAP code]

```
CLASS zpo_hello_world DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC.

  PUBLIC SECTION.
  INTERFACES if_oo_adt_classrun.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.


CLASS zpo_hello_world IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD if_oo_adt_classrun~main.
  out->write( |Hello World ! ({ cl_abap_context_info=>get_user_alias( ) })| ).

  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: do your user have an alias? have a look in su01

Comment: There should be a fiori application [maintain business users](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_CLOUD/a630d57fc5004c6383e7a81efee7a8bb/e40e710321c74f28916affa9ae984bce.html?locale=en-US) for maintaining users in an ABAP cloud system, including setting the users alias.

Comment: do you run your console app in the productive BTP? Trial one does not support SU01 fiori tile

Answer (score 1):

Some of the methods in `cl_abap_context_info` can only be used in a cloud environment.

```
cl_abap_context_info=>
```

| New Method | Old Environemnt |
| --- | --- |
| ET_SYSTEM_DATE | SYST-DATUM |
| GET_SYSTEM_TIME | SYST-UZEIT |
| GET_USER_TECHNICAL_NAME | SYST-UNAME |
| GET_USER_LANGUAGE_ABAP_FORMAT | SYST-LANGU |
| GET_USER_LANGUAGE_ISO_FORMAT | ISO format for language |
| GET_USER_TIME_ZONE | SYST-TZONE |
| GET_USER_ALIAS | Alias of user master data (Cloud) |
| GET_SYSTEM_URL | URL of the system (Cloud) |
| GET_USER_FORMATTED_NAME | BAPI_USER_GET_DETAIL |
| GET_USER_DESCRIPTION | BAPI_USER_GET_DETAIL |
| GET_USER_BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID | Business-Partner-ID of the user (Cloud) |

(see [here](https://software-heroes.com/en/blog/abap-context-info-explained))

Thus means if you run On-Premise those methods will not return any value as far as I know.

But I just saw that you are using the BTP abap cloud example. I've also tested it here it seems that there no alias is set for the users.

You can verify your user with the `get_user_business_partner_id`-method which is only valid in cloud.

```
  METHOD if_oo_adt_classrun~main.
    TRY.
        out->write( |Hello World { cl_abap_context_info=>get_user_business_partner_id( ) }| ).
      CATCH cx_abap_context_info_error.
    ENDTRY.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

I'm not sure weather you can set a user alias with transaction `SU1` due there is no SAP Gui support I guess.